# What will happen to my Windows PC if I visit a site from a network marked as malicious by google safebrowsing

Tags: network, malware, google, safe-browsing-filter

Google rated a whole network in china as malicious: http://www.google.com/safebrowsing/diagnostic?site=AS:4134

Quite a few of our customers have their websites hosted in that network (e.g. http://www.hbgdfy.com/). I told my colleagues not to ignore the google safebrowsing and actually avoid those websites for now.

They are doing so, but asked me what could actually happen if they still did go on those websites. I tried to find out why the network got flagged or what could happen, but I couldn't find much.

Do you know any details what would happen to our windows PC's if we actually visited those websites or is it not possible to predict?
Thanks for any info!

Comment: Unfortunately this is quite a broad topic.  The answer depends on several different technologies (e.g. browsers used, certificates installed, web technologies used by the network) and what security measures a user's computer might have.  There are just too many ways that ignoring a warning could go wrong.

Comment: I suppose, there are just too many factors... I was just too curious if someone could go into detail :)

Answer (score 0):

If the entire network block is marked as malicious by Google, a lot of innocent sites will end up marked as malicious, as you have seen.

If you are sure that the site you want to visit is not malicious, you can navigate to them and nothing bad will happen. That message is just a warning. Your web filtering software (if installed and updated) can protect you.

Answer (score -2):

According to Google:

`Of the 148000 site(s) we tested on this network over the past 90 days, 3065 site(s), including, for example, yxdown.cn/, 97sky.cn/, cr173.com/, served content that resulted in malicious software being downloaded and installed without user consent.`

The malicious software usually is **Cross-site scripts (XSS)**, these are scripts that can bypass the browser access controls. They can:

- Access *session cookies*: The attacker has the ability to take control of sessions not fully closed (for example, if you didn't logout of your *bank* website).
- Inject ads on on every website you visit.
- Altering browser functionality: For example redirect the normal navigation to forged sites imitating the legitimate one.
- Identity theft.
- Use of your equipment as a slave on Denial of Service attacks.
- Spying on user’s web browsing habits.

Comment: An XSS on a website can't magically inject ads on any other website you visit nor alter browser functionality, nor can it spy on your other browsing activity besides on the compromised site.